# how to catch the error message in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am not able to capture the error message that is printed in REPL, I would like to have it as a string or any other type that can be printed later, is this possible in Common Lisp? This is something common in other languages, such as Javascript:

```
var myError = undefined;
try {
    some();
}catch(e){
    myError = e.message;
}
```

Of course in Common Lisp this would not work like this, after all it will not return an error object like in JavaScript, but I wonder if there is any way to catch the error message, so I do not need to print it when the error happens, but when I want.

**I'm using:**
SBCL

I'm trying:

```
CL-USER> (handler-case (/ 3 0)
  (division-by-zero (c)
    (defvar *my-error* c)))
; in: HANDLER-CASE (/ 3 0)
;     (/ 3 0)
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   Lisp error during constant folding:
;   arithmetic error DIVISION-BY-ZERO signalled
;   Operation was (/ 3 0).
;
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
*MY-ERROR*
CL-USER> *my-error*
#<DIVISION-BY-ZERO {1004486093}>
```

What I want to capture is the following message to print later:

```
; in: HANDLER-CASE (/ 3 0)
;     (/ 3 0)
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   Lisp error during constant folding:
;   arithmetic error DIVISION-BY-ZERO signalled
;   Operation was (/ 3 0).
;
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

Comment: don't use DEFVAR inside code...

Answer (score 3):

```
CL-USER> (write *my-error* :escape nil)
arithmetic error DIVISION-BY-ZERO signalled
Operation was (/ 3 0).
#<DIVISION-BY-ZERO {100369B843}>
```

The same can be achieved with `format`, using the `~a` directive:

```
CL-USER> (with-standard-io-syntax (format nil "~a" *my-error*))
"arithmetic error DIVISION-BY-ZERO signalled
Operation was (/ 3 0)."
```

Be careful, you are using `defvar`, and so the variable will not be assigned if you execute the same code twice. Better define a function that returns a string, and use local variables.

> What I want to capture is the following message

That message is specific to how your environment prints error messages, it is more difficult to capture, maybe you could bind your own string-stream and capture the whole output (?), but I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Comment: I used "defvar" just for quick experimentation here. But even so the error is still issued with handler-case, I wanted it not to be printed, and I printed this message that you informed me how to print, when I wished.

Comment: @PerduGames No problem, the remark was also intended for other people reading the answer :-)

Comment: @PerduGames: defvar is the wrong tool for quick experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

You did catch the condition, hence you can reproduce the *error* message, but it seems you want to catch the *SBCL compilation warning*. Thus, it is independent from the condition.

I don't have the solution, yet you should search in another direction IMO (how to catch SBCL warnings, etc).

As said, you shouldn't use `defvar`. You can use `setf` instead, even if you didn't `defvar` a variable before. In that case, you'll get another warning:

```
; in: HANDLER-CASE (/ 3 0)
;     (SETF *MY-ERROR* C)
; ==>
;   (SETQ *MY-ERROR* C)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: *MY-ERROR*
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     *MY-ERROR*
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

btw, it seems you are using the Cookbook aren't you ? :)